# Error: Validation failed: cannot load kubecfg settings for "demo.k8s.naveen.tk": context "demo.k8s.naveen.tk" does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I'm trying to validate Kubernetes cluster using kops validate command, but it throws this error:

> Error: Validation failed: cannot load kubecfg settings for "demo.k8s.naveen.tk": context "demo.k8s.naveen.tk" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `kops update cluster --name demo.k8s.naveen.tk --yes` yet? That command should automatically create the context.

You can also run `kops export kubecfg --name demo.k8s.naveen.tk --admin`, which will create a temporary admin certificate.